# canvas only target certain particles for clearing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this code that stacks canvas particles in a lane and then resets the whole canvas when one lane is full.

It does this by setting "particles = []"

I want to modify this behavior by only resetting the canvas for that particular lane. Is it possible?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

"use strict";

var c = document.getElementById("c"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    WIDTH = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT = c.height = window.innerHeight;

var particles = [],
    particle = null,
    particleCount = 3,
    radius = 0,
    numParticles = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    colors = ["#00FF6D", "E8D90C", "#FF5900", "#C00CE8", "#0D90FF"];

var Vector = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
};

Vector.prototype = {
    constructor: Vector,
    add: function (v) {
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
    },
    sub: function (v) {
        this.x -= v.x;
        this.y -= v.y;
    },
    mul: function (v) {
        this.x *= v.x;
        this.y *= v.y;
    }
};

var Particle = function (position, velocity, radius, lane, color) {
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.baseRadius = radius;
    this.angle = 3;
    this.lane = lane;
    this.color = color;

};

Particle.prototype = {
    constructor: Particle,
    update: function (lane) {
        this.radius = 3;
        this.angle += 10;
        this.position.add(this.velocity);

        // CHECKS FIRST IF THERE'S ALREADY A PARTICLE IN THE LANE AND THEN SHORTENS THE STOP LENGTH
        if (this.position.x > WIDTH - (numParticles[this.lane] + 1) * 120) {

            // IF THERE IS ALREADY A PARTICLE ON A LANE THE NUMBER OF PARTICLES PER IS INCREASED
            if (this.velocity.x > 0) {
                console.log(numParticles[this.lane] + " particles in this lane")
                numParticles[this.lane]++;

                if (numParticles[this.lane] > 8) {
                    numParticles[this.lane] = 0;
                    particles = [];
                }
                // STOPS THE PARTICLE
                this.velocity.x = 0;
            }
        }
    },
    render: function (ctx) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                ctx.arc(this.position.x - i * 12, (this.position.y - 30) + j * 12, this.radius + 0.5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
        }
    }
};



function addParticle(lane) {
    radius = 3;
    particle = new Particle(
        new Vector(-radius, lane * (HEIGHT) / 5),
        new Vector(5),
        radius,
        lane,
        colors[Math.round(Math.random() * 4)]
    );
    particles.push(particle);
}

requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    for (var i = 0, len = particles.length; i < len; i++) {
        particle = particles[i];
        particle.update();
        particle.render(ctx);
    }
});

//
// ─── SOCKETIO CONNECTION TO NODE WEBSERVER RUNNING OPENCV ───────────────────────
//
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

// SEND "CONNECTED" MESSAGE ONCE SUCCSEFULLY CONNECTED   
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');
});

socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);

    // IF NUMBER OF CARS DETECTED IS MORE THAN 0, A PARTICLE WILL BE ADDED RANDOMLY TO ONE OF THE 4 LANES
    if (msg >= 0) {
        addParticle(Math.round((Math.random() * 3) + 1));
    }
});});
```

Comment: It looks like lane is a property of Particle (looking at addParticle(lane){...}) ... I imagine that when you want to clear a lane, you already know which lane to clear - can't you go through your particles and check the lane, and only remove the ones with the same lane?

Answer (score 0):

### Filtering arrays

If you have an array of particles and want to remove some items that satisfy some condition, there are a few ways to do it.

#### Array.filter

Create a new array using Array.filter

```
var particles = []; // fill with particles
// remove particles in lane 3 using arrow function
particles = particles.filter(particle => particle.lane !== 3);
// or using via function
particles = particles.filter(function(particle){ return particle.lane !== 3});
```

This method does create a new array so incurs some penalties due to GC (Garbage collection) and allocation overheads. Also if you have more than one referance to the array you need to up date all references.

```
var particles = [];
const obj = {
    particles : particles,  // referance to the array particles.
}


// remove particles in lane 3
particles = particles.filter(particle => particle.lane !== 3)
// the array referenced by obj.particles still has the unfiltered array
obj.particles = particles; // update reference
```

#### Array.splice to filter

When there is need to performance you can use Array.splice to remove items from the array. It also has the advantage of not creating a new referance that you would have to propagate.

```
 for(var i = 0; i <particles.length; i++){  // must use particles.length
     if(particles[i].lane === 3){
         particles.splice(i--,1); // decrease i so you do not skip an item
                                  // as slice will move the index of all 
                                  // items above i down one
     }
  }

  // do not use a variable to store the length in the for loop
  var len = particles.length
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){  // will cause unexpected behaviors because
                                 // the array length will change
```

#### Flag active

For the best performance you would assign a flag to all particles that determines if the particle is updated and rendered.

```
 for(var i = 0; i <particles.length; i++){  
     particles[i].active = ! particles[i].lane === 3;
 }
```

Before you update and render you would check if active is true

```
 // in render and update loops
 for(var i = 0; i <particles.length; i++){  
      if(particles[i].active){
          particles[i].update(); // or render()  

      }
 }
```

There is of course the fact you have a growing array. To stop the uncontroled growth of the array you change the way you set the particle properties adding a method to the particle object.

```
 function Particle(){}; // constructor
 Particle.prototype.set = function(pos,vel,foo,bar){
     this.active = true;
     this.velocity = vel;
     //... and the other properties

 }
```

The when you add a particle you first check if there is an inactive particle in the particles array and use that by setting its properties with the set function. If there are no inactive particles then you just create a new particle and add it to the particles array setting its properties with set.

```
 function addParticle(pos,vel,foo,bar){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
         if(! particles[i].active){
             particles[i].set(pos,vel,foo,bar);
             return;
         }
     }
     // no inactive particles create a new one
     particles.push(
        new Particle().set(pos,vel,foo,bar);
     );
 }
```